An exercise to remember all 7th chords?
I'm a somewhere between beginner and intermediate piano/keyboard player with interest in RnB, Neo-Soul, Gospel and Jazz. I have learned off Youtube the basics of music theory, and I am comfortable with doing some basic improvisation in any key using minor/major/pentatonic/blues scales.
I find however that, unless I'm playing a cover for a song I already know the chords of, I struggle to play interesting chords when improvising (I will usually just vamp between the 5 and the 1, and play random triads in between). To fix this, I am starting to drill reharm exercises and I find that, outside of the most basic ones (major/minor triads and 7ths in root position), I always need a few seconds to form a chord. Hence my
Question : What exercises can I drill to be able to play any 7th (major, minor, dominant, half-diminished) chord at a moment's notice ?
For now, what I do is pick a key and arpeggiate each 7th diatonic chord up and down the keyboard, but so far I don't feel like it has helped much in my playing (granted I started very recently...)
Thank you for your time !
